# VBA macro to return the lowest value in a list?

Tags: excel, vba, minimum

I am trying to write a VBA Excel macro that will return the lowest value in a list (column C) and place the answer in cell "G3".

```
Sub LowestSales2()
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Range("C2:C" & Rows.Count)
    Range("G3").Value.Low = c
End Sub
```

Comment: @BigBen Apologies, I attached my current code and my main problem has been using the "print" function to put my result in G3. And I am required to use a macro when of course a simple MIN function would be good enough.

Comment: [Application.WorksheetFunction.Min](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.min)

Comment: Avoid pasting code images in the question. Please delete the image. Copy and paste the code instead of posting an image.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of the range. Take your pick...

**OPTION 1**

This option will insert a formula in cell `G3`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ws.Range("G3").Formula = "=MIN(C:C)"
End Sub
```

**OPTION 2**

Use `Evaluate` in case you do not want the formula.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ws.Range("G3").Value = ws.Evaluate("MIN(C:C)")
End Sub
```

**OPTION 3**

As Raymond suggested, use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Min`. This option will insert the minimum value in `G3`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    ws.Range("G3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ws.Columns(3))
End Sub
```

Comment: Friendly hint: Option 2 may deliver unwanted results as it's *not* fully qualified; using a [worksheet related evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate) would be the simplest way to resolve this issue: `ws.Range("G3").Value = ws.Evaluate("MIN(C:C)")` :-) @SiddharthRout

Comment: @T.M.: Good Point! Updated the post. Thanks